# Is the limit of a convergent sequence always a limit point of the sequence or the range of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In this video lecture ([Real analysis, HMC,2010, by Prof. Su](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEx3Ys6JAJo&index=15&list=PL0E754696F72137EC)) Professor Francis Su says (around 54:30) that "If a sequence $\{p_n\}$ converges to a point $p$ it does not necessarily mean $p$ is a limit point of the *range of*  $\{p_n\}$." I'm not sure how that can hold (except in case of a constant sequence).

I'm not able to understand the difference between the set $\{p_n\}$ and the range of $\{p_n\}$ (which I understand is the set of all values attained by $p_n$). As per my understanding they're the same (except $\{p_n\}$ might contain some repeated values which the range of $p_n$ won't, e.g. the range of the sequence {1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/3,1/3,1/3,1/3,1/4,1/4,...} would be {1/2,1/3,1/4,...}, or that of the constant sequence {1,1,1,...} would be {1}.

Based on this understanding, my reasoning is as follows: By the definition of a convergent sequence $\{p_n\}$ converging to $p$, for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ we can find an infinite number of terms of $\{p_n\}$ which lie at a distance less than $\epsilon $ from p, i.e. within an $\epsilon $-neighborhood of $p$. Hence *every* $\epsilon $-neighborhood of p contains an infinite number of points of the set $\{p_n\}$ other than itself ($p$). Hence $p$ is a limit point of $\{p_n\}$.

Now this would not hold only in case of a constant sequence, which converges, but any neighborhood of of its limit cannot contain any points in common with the sequence *other than itself*. Hence the limit won't be a limit point of the sequence.

Other than this special case, I cannot think of any situation where the limit of a convergent sequence is not also a limit point of the sequence.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sequences which are eventually constant also work.

Comment: No I absolutely agree that this is not true for a constant sequence, as I've explained. Just wanted to double check if there's any other case where this might hold, which I'm missing out.

Comment: You can also take any sequence that is eventually a constant sequence.

Comment: Range of $\{ p_n \}$? What is a range of a set? You can talk about a range of a map. I've never heard of the former before.

Comment: Thanks a ton JoeyZou and Cm7F7Bb. I didn't know the concept of an eventually constant sequence. Found out based on your guidance. Thanks!

Comment: @Nameless The "range" of a sequence would be the set of its values, i.e. $\{p_n: n=1,2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @Nameless: Also consider that a sequence in $\Bbb R$ is a function $\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ using a classical, but otherwise seldom used function notation.

Answer (score 3):

Another [counter] example. Define a sequence in $(\mathcal{R},d)$ such that

$a_{n} := 5-n$ for $n \leq 5$ and

$a_{n} := 0$ for all $n > 5$

This sequence converges to 0 (zero). The range of this sequence viewed as a function from natural numbers to the real numbers is the following set

$A=\{4,3,2,1,0\}$.

0 (zero) is not a limit point in this set since any $0 < r < 1$ will produce a neighborhood around 0 (zero) that will not include other points of this set $A$.